# fscanf wont work - Program is casting an error

Tags: c, scanf

I have some problem in `fscanf` function. I'm new in C, and I wanted to make reading lines from the file and save them to structure, but it seems, that I don't understand it well ^^.

```
PATIENT *patientTab;
int tabSize = 0;
int patientCount = 0;
PATIENT temp;
int tempIndex = 0;

if (openFile()){
    printf("Plik otworzony!\n\n");
    while(fscanf(dataBase, "%s %f",
    &temp.patientNumber,
    &temp.patientGender,
    &temp.patientLength,
    &temp.patientWeigth,
    &temp.patientHeadCircuit,
    &temp.patientApperance,
    &temp.patientPulse,
    &temp.patientGrimace,
    &temp.patientActivity,
    &temp.patientRespiration)
        != EOF){

            if (patientCount + 1 >= tabSize){
                tabSize += 5;
                patientTab = realloc(patientTab, sizeof(int) * tabSize);
            }

                for (tempIndex; tempIndex < 5; tempIndex++){

                    patientTab[patientCount].patientNumber[tempIndex] = temp.patientNumber[tempIndex];

                }

            patientTab[patientCount].patientGender = temp.patientGender;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientLength = temp.patientLength;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientWeigth = temp.patientLength;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientHeadCircuit = temp.patientHeadCircuit;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientApperance = temp.patientApperance;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientPulse = temp.patientPulse;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientGrimace = temp.patientGrimace;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientActivity = temp.patientActivity;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientRespiration = temp.patientRespiration;
            patientCount++;

        }

    //free(temp);
    fclose(dataBase);
} 
else endProgram();
```

dataBase is global.

The problem is when the program tries to loop "while", which include "fscanf" function, the program is casting an error and the only think, which I can do is shut down the program. I found an example on the internet, but it was a simple example with one variable. I'm sure the problem is my declaration with many parameters with "&temp".

The structure is:

```
typedef struct Patient {

char patientNumber[5];
char patientGender;
double patientLength;
float patientWeigth;
float patientHeadCircuit;
int patientApperance;
int patientPulse;
int patientGrimace;
int patientActivity;
int patientRespiration;

}PATIENT;
```

...and this is the fragment of content file:
[txt link](http://www.beetxt.com/BMB/)

Comment: What is this mess? your `scanf` format string is for two parameters only. And you are passing like a zillion of them.

Comment: The values of all the other members of the struct will be indeterminate, because the struct `temp` was not initialised. UB.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by using only **two** format tags to read into **10** variables:    `while(fscanf(dataBase, "%s %f", &temp.patientNumber, &temp.patientGender, &temp.patientLength, &temp.patientWeigth, &temp.patientHeadCircuit, &temp.patientApperance,  &temp.patientPulse, &temp.patientGrimace,  &temp.patientActivity, &temp.patientRespiration)` ?

Comment: `%f` for `patientGender`? Hmm... is that an assumption ;)

Comment: Maybe there is a problem, you know, i thought, that "&s &f" worked in another way :D, but i will fix it :)

Comment: Using %s for reading patientNumber (which is declared as char[5]) is dangerous. What if there are more than 4 characters entered? (Answer: you will write outside the allocated space).

Comment: Time to [read the manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y6s16x1.aspx)? There is an example of multiple inputs or various different types.

Comment: At this moment i have this http://wklej.org/id/2592531/

but this function "openFile()" is casting "[Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]" after "dataBase"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are referring to the content in link http://www.beetxt.com/BMB/

Please change
1)

```
while(fscanf(dataBase, "%s %f",
    &temp.patientNumber,
    &temp.patientGender,
    &temp.patientLength,
    &temp.patientWeigth,
    &temp.patientHeadCircuit,
    &temp.patientApperance,
    &temp.patientPulse,
    &temp.patientGrimace,
    &temp.patientActivity,
    &temp.patientRespiration)
```

with

```
while(fscanf(dataBase, "%s %c %lf %f %f %d %d %d %d %d",
    temp.patientNumber,
    &temp.patientGender,
    &temp.patientLength,
    &temp.patientWeigth,
    &temp.patientHeadCircuit,
    &temp.patientApperance,
    &temp.patientPulse,
    &temp.patientGrimace,
    &temp.patientActivity,
    &temp.patientRespiration)
```

2)

```
if (patientCount + 1 >= tabSize){
                tabSize += 5;
                patientTab = realloc(patientTab, sizeof(int) * tabSize);
            }
```

With

```
if (patientCount + 1 >= tabSize){
                tabSize += 5;
                patientTab = realloc(patientTab, sizeof(PATIENT) * tabSize);
            }
```

3)

```
for (tempIndex; tempIndex < 5; tempIndex++){

                    patientTab[patientCount].patientNumber[tempIndex] = temp.patientNumber[tempIndex];

                }

            patientTab[patientCount].patientGender = temp.patientGender;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientLength = temp.patientLength;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientWeigth = temp.patientLength;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientHeadCircuit = temp.patientHeadCircuit;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientApperance = temp.patientApperance;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientPulse = temp.patientPulse;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientGrimace = temp.patientGrimace;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientActivity = temp.patientActivity;
            patientTab[patientCount].patientRespiration = temp.patientRespiration;
            patientCount++;
```

with

```
for (tempIndex; tempIndex < 5; tempIndex++){
    strcpy(patientTab[patientCount].patientNumber[tempIndex] = temp.patientNumber[tempIndex]);
    patientTab[patientCount].patientGender = temp.patientGender;
    patientTab[patientCount].patientLength = temp.patientLength;
    patientTab[patientCount].patientWeigth = temp.patientLength;
    patientTab[patientCount].patientHeadCircuit = temp.patientHeadCircuit;
    patientTab[patientCount].patientApperance = temp.patientApperance;
    patientTab[patientCount].patientPulse = temp.patientPulse;
    patientTab[patientCount].patientGrimace = temp.patientGrimace;
    patientTab[patientCount].patientActivity = temp.patientActivity;
    patientTab[patientCount].patientRespiration = temp.patientRespiration;
    patientCount++;

}
```

Hope this works fine.. And change `char patientNumber[5];` to `char patientNumber[6];`

Comment: Well, i didnt mind about removing '&' before patientNumber in while loop, and patientTab needed malloc, but everything works now. Thank you :)

Comment: It works with realloc also.. Just change first line `PATIENT *patientTab;` to `PATIENT *patientTab = NULL;`

Comment: the realloc is still there, i just put line like "patientTab = malloc(5 * sizeof(PATIENT));"  before while loop, because the fragment with realloc caused error... but, i think putting "null" is good thing too :D

Comment: The answer may work no doubt, but if it doesn't explain "why" (even just with a link to fscanf's man page), it is not so useful as it might be. Same goes for 6 instead of 5 - the OP will just be taught a spell by rote, or learn to program by trial and error ("oh wait, let's make the buffer a bit longer").